# Status in parser must be an automatic

Tags: python, json, parsing

I have a code that displays the parser from the RFBR website. And in two variations. One of them goes to the contest link. The other one retrieves data from tables from the "Competitions" page.

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import chardet
import xlsxwriter
import re
from datetime import date, timedelta

PAGES_COUNT = 1
OUT_FILENAME = 'out.json'

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")


def get_soup(url, **kwargs):
    response = requests.get(url, **kwargs, verify=False)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, features='html.parser')
    else:
        soup = None
    return soup


def crawl_products(pages_count):
    urls = []
    fmt = 'https://www.rfbr.ru/rffi/ru/contest?CONTEST_STATUS_ID=-1&CONTEST_TYPE=-1&CONTEST_YEAR=-1&page={page}'
    for page_n in range(1, 1 + pages_count):
        print('page: {}'.format(page_n))

        page_url = fmt.format(page=page_n)
        soup = get_soup(page_url)
        if soup is None:
            break

        for tag in soup.select('.tr .link'):
            href = tag.attrs['href']
            url = 'https://www.rfbr.ru/rffi/ru/contest{}'.format(href)
            urls.append(url)
    return urls


def parse_products(urls):
    data = []

    for url in urls:
        print('product: {}'.format(url))

        soup = get_soup(url)
        if soup is None:
            break

        for j in soup.find_all("main", {"class":"template__main"}):
            for jj in j.find_all("div", {"class":"sfc l-3 mt-5 mb-10 lh-xl"}):
                ja = re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7f]', r'', str(jj))
                jo = re.sub(r'\<[^>]*\>', '', str(ja))
                ji = re.sub(r'_', '', str(jo))
                ju = re.sub(r'  ', '', str(ji))
                je = re.sub(r' :', '', str(ju))
                jy = je[13:]
                amount = jy
        rponse = requests.get(url, verify=False)
        sp = BeautifulSoup(rponse.text, "lxml")
        document = {}
        item = {}
        dcs = sp(attrs={"class": "list-in article"})
        for z in dcs:
            document[z.h2.text] = list(z.ol.stripped_strings)
            # document[z.h2.text] = tuple(z.ol.stripped_strings)

        # в одну строку с разделителем запятая
        for z in dcs:
            document[z.h2.text] = ', '.join(z.ol.stripped_strings)
        try:
            article = [l.get_text(strip=True) for l in soup.find_all("p") if l.get_text(strip=True)]
            art = str(article).replace("['", '').replace("']", '')
        except:
            article = [l.get_text(strip=True) for l in soup.find_all("h3") if l.get_text(strip=True)]
            art = str(article).replace("['", '').replace("']", '')
        for row in soup.select('td'):
            cols = row.select('td')
            cols = [c.text.strip() for c in cols]
        name = [i.get_text(strip=True) for i in soup.find_all("h1") if i.get_text(strip=True)]
        ame = str(name).replace("['", '').replace("']", '')
        item['Название'] = ame
        item['Статус'] = "Заявки не принимаются"
        item['Время окончания приема заявок'] = amount
        item['Полное описание условий конкурса'] = art
        item['Документы'] = document
        data.append(item)

    return data


def dump_to_json(filename, data, **kwargs):
    kwargs.setdefault('ensure_ascii', False)
    kwargs.setdefault('indent', 1)

    with open(OUT_FILENAME, 'w', encoding="utf-8") as f:
        json.dump(data, f, **kwargs)


def main():
    urls = crawl_products(PAGES_COUNT)
    data = parse_products(urls)
    dump_to_json(OUT_FILENAME, data)

    with open(OUT_FILENAME, 'w', encoding="utf-8") as f:
        json.dump(data, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import os
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
from urllib.parse import unquote
 
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
 
BASE_URL = 'https://www.rfbr.ru/rffi/ru/contest'
 
session = requests.Session()
session.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:100.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/100.0'
 
items = []
max_page = 82
for page in range(1, max_page + 1):
    url = f'{BASE_URL}/?page={page}' if page > 1 else BASE_URL
    print(url) 
    rs = session.get(url, verify=False)
    rs.raise_for_status() 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(rs.content, 'html.parser')
    for item in soup.select('.tr'):
        number = [d.get_text(strip=True) for d in item if d.get_text(strip=True)].pop(2)
        time = [d.get_text(strip=True) for d in item if d.get_text(strip=True)].pop(3)
        title = item.select_one("img").get('alt')
        items.append({
            'Название': number,
            'Статус': title,
            'Время окончания приема заявок': time,
        })
with open('out2.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(items, f, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
```

All these codes output results in JSON

Result of the first code:

```
 {
  "Название": "Конкурс на лучшие научные проекты фундаментальных исследований в сфере общественно-политических наук, реализуемые молодыми учеными, проводимый совместно РФФИ и ЭИСИ",
  "Статус": "Заявки не принимаются",
  "Время окончания приема заявок": "15.03.2021 23:59",
  "Полное описание условий конкурса": "много текста",
  "Документы": {
   "Формы заявок": {}
  }
 },
```

```
[
    {
        "Название": "Конкурс на лучшие научные проекты фундаментальных исследований в сфере общественно-политических наук, реализуемые молодыми учеными, проводимый совместно РФФИ и ЭИСИ",
        "Статус": "Заявки не принимаются",
        "Время окончания приема заявок": "15.03.2021 23:59"
    },
```

It seems to be nothing. But the matter is that in the first code the array "Статус" is entered manually. And it needs to output automatically. That is, it displayed not only the value "Заявки не принимаются", but also "Конкурс завершен", if this is the status in the table. I tried to insert elements from the second into the first code, which switch directly to the table, and not to the page of this or that code. There didn't seem to be any mistakes. But there all the time there was the same value - "Заявки не принимаются." In other cases, the code simply stopped working.

In the second code everything happens automatically.

How to correctly transfer elements from the second code to the first one so that the status of the competition is determined automatically according to the table?

Link: https://www.rfbr.ru/rffi/ru/contest